# Azure functions on Premises - Why use a Docker container?

Tags: azure, docker, runtime, azure-functions

What is the purpose of using Docker container for Azure functions on Premises (runtime V2)?

Doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-install

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Functions Runtime is a container orchestrator specialized for Azure Functions.

Docker is used to deploy and manage containers.You can develop and run Azure Function cross platform or on premises with docker support.
You could refer to this [article](http://www.zdnet.com/article/what-is-docker-and-why-is-it-so-darn-popular/) for the benefits of using Docker container.

Besides,if you want to learn the usage of running Azure Function App 2.0 in a Docker container,you could refer to this [article](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/run-azure-functions-in-docker/#creating-the-docker-container).

> **Conclusion**
>
> You are now able to run Azure Functions where ever you want, even on AWS or on premises.

Comment: It is not very well documented and is very much WIP